# Only unknown data type in SQLDeveloper

Tags: ubuntu, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have been using SQLDeveloper a while and I made a schema in it. But now, for some reason, when I open this schema, all the data types are set to "unknown".

When I open a new schema and create an entity, I only have 'unknown' option for logical data type, nothing else.

I am not aware of changing anything, so I am lost. Has anyone encountered anything like this?
*(in kubuntu, I can't take a screenshot of a dropdown menu, for some reason, but it contains only one value - unknown)*
[image]

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling it?

Comment: I dont have a native installation for my system, so it only comes as a zip. Yes. I have tried downloading and running it anew, but the settings are still there (connections, history).

Comment: Okay. Renaming (essentially removing) `~/.sqldeveloper` folder helped, but I'd still like to know what caused this in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing ~/.sqldeveloper folder helped. I found no better approach.

Comment: I also had this issue and removing/renaming the preferences folder also fixed it. I'm on Windows 7, so my preferences folder was located in C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Roaming\Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler.

Answer (score 4):

in Tools | Preferences | Data Modeler options just set the Default System Types Distionary to "(datamodeler localization on your hard drive)" & "\datamodeler\datamodel\types". Maybe this will help you like it helped me.

Comment: This one worked for me, I've lost all my custom defined domains though.

Answer (score 0):

I also just had this problem.  I renamed the old preferences directory as indicated, then ran Data Modeler.  When it asked if I wanted to import old preferences, I navigated to the renamed directory and had to identify a version twice-removed (system4.0.3.853, system4.1.0.881 didn't work) from the current version (system4.1.3.901) before I got my datatypes back.

Thank you.  I will start including this in my backups.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools -> perfreences -> Data modeler -> model select data types from All Logical types and drag to prefered logical data type.

Answer (score 0):

I went to Tools > Preferences > Data Modeler and cleared out what was in the "Default System Types Directory" (leaving it blank).  I saved it and everything re-appeared.